# "Nothing to show" when I tried to insert a new Vector Asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable, xml-drawable, android-studio-4.1

["Nothing to show" error - vector asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRXnU.png)

Hey, all. So, recently I updated my Android Studio Version to 4.1 (the latest version). I wanted to add a vector asset just like the usual but..somehow..the preview of the icons did not show up. I can't choose a vector asset or even add one. Is there any way to fix this? Or maybe, a way to downgrade the version? Thank you so much :(

Comment: I could see the vector drawable in Android Studio 4.1. The issue would be with the up-gradation. Try clearing cache and restarting. If no luck, check for updates to confirm the update is completed properly.

Comment: I tried to clean and build the project, invalidate cache/restart android studio and check for the updates. The result is still the same, sadly..

Comment: when I open this in AS it takes a few seconds to load which suggests it may be coming from an online source. Is your internet good? Failing that I'd look to reinstall AS

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, my internet connection is just fine. I think I might have to try reinstalling AS. I cleaned ,rebuilt the project so many times. I even restarted my own computer lol. But, it's still not showing up.

Comment: I tried reinstalling but it didn't solve the problem..

Comment: @TinaraNathania this also happened to me. It was very sudden. It actually happened while I was using Android Studio. One minute the icons show, the next minute the icons are gone forever. Uninstalling/reinstalling did not fix it. I am going to bet thousands of users have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems to be originated with the Android Studio Windows version 4.1. I have the same exact problem and I went back to version 4.0.1. With the previous version Asset Studio clip art works fine. It also works fine the Android Studio version 4.1 for mac OS.

Update:

I found out why it isn't displaying the icons. For some reason when the Windows user name's folder has a space, it can't load the images and it only shows the message "Nothing to show".
I had to change the folder name and eliminate the space in order to make it work.

Comment: Check the update. That solved the problem but it is something a lot hard than it sounds.

Comment: This also happened to me! This is a real problem. After this, clearing the cache and uninstalling, reinstalling Android Studio does not fix it! I noticed THIS IMMEDIATELY. As I was browsing these pre-made icons, I exited the Asset Studio and looked up other random icons on Google. Then I decided to use an Asset studio icon so I opened up Asset Studio and clicked on "clip art". Now the library does not show a single pre-made icon! What in the world is going on!!!??

Comment: Hey Answer on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382564/how-i-fix-nothing-to-show-in-my-vector-asset-in-android-studio
Thanks ! You fixed my issue

Comment: The fix which requires renaming the user folder is not going to work on Windows 10 Home Edition because changing the folder name requires the 'Local Users and Groups' utility which is deactivated in the Home Edition. This problem needs to be reported to Google and they must release a Patch for Android Studio.

Comment: i agree with you ever since i updated my studio this happened

Answer (score 1):

I'm faced with the same issue, I fixed this issue by moving **Android** folder from
**C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local**
to any different folder (**C:\Users**) and in Android Studio Goto **File -> Project Structure...** and in **SDK Location** set new SDK location.

Comment: Wow, I had issues with changing the user name folder, so I just stopped using Android Asset Studio's built-in library. I think your solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem a few days ago, however what finally worked for me was, changing the name of the **icons** folder in **C:\Users\User-name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk** to **icon**.

*Note: I am using **Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2** on **Windows 11 ver 23H2**