# Android Studio 4.1 icons not visible, How to get it?

Tags: android, icons

**icon list not showing for adding new icon using Image/Vector Asset in Android Studio 4.1**
[Screen Shot Im getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUPrI.png)

Comment: Stack overflow is a board for programmers.
Maybe you should check out Android Studio support?
If I were to guess, you didn't link any icons the correct way.

Comment: Everyone is having this problem and Google needs a Patch to fix this. Check these discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64429556/nothing-to-show-when-i-tried-to-insert-a-new-vector-asset-in-android-studio
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382564/how-i-fix-nothing-to-show-in-my-vector-asset-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ranamed my Android SDK's folder name from "Android SDK" to "AndroidSDK" (removed space of folder name)

After that, Reset your Android SDK path(renamed folder's path) in Android Studio from SDK Manager

[image: Then I Got All Icons]