# Empty Clipart in IntelliJ IDEA's Android Image/Vector Asset

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 and Android SDK 29. When I open a project to add some system icons, I use the Image Asset feature in the IDE and open the clipart library, and it shows nothing
[as in this  screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QOwQ.png)

I installed Android Studio alongside with IntelliJ and its clipart library is available, while that of IntelliJ is still empty.

I have also found out this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382564/how-i-fix-nothing-to-show-in-my-vector-asset-in-android-studio) for the Vector Asset in Android Studio, but its solution doesn't work for me as the icon folder has content inside and my SDK path contains no space character.

How can I load the IntelliJ's Android clipart?

Comment: What do you mean by not available space in your SDK? Isn't it possible to move it on the disk with enough space and add assets to SDK?

Comment: Did you ask for "my SDK path contains no space"? I mean that the directory path of my SDK does not contain any space characters.

Comment: Then just download the icons and place to icons folder as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464135/8203759