# Standard Android material icons set not available

Tags: android, android-studio

material design icons are not available in Android Studio. It only shows a few pieces. I want to show all icons. How can I solve this problem?

I don't want to reinstall.

[image]

Comment: Which icon do you want?

Comment: I want all icons to appear.

Comment: Can you try this: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVTY4Vn6Lv8)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382564/how-i-fix-nothing-to-show-in-my-vector-asset-in-android-studio

Comment: The asset dialog only shows some of these icons..
[And here is the solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69149534/22833303)

Comment: Thanks @NaliniDarandale.How to open the Select Icon dialog box. It is not available in the new android studio.